# Php PDO and Get Method not working in clean url after rewrite my htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

Please i have a problem with my PHP PDO, MOD-REWRITE AND GET METHOD.
I rewrite my website to use clean url, and using the php pdo to read posted article the old link look like this

http://example.com/questions.php?postid=145

while after rewrite it look like this

http://example.com/questions/postid/145

But my problem is when i try to read the article using clean url it will not load well or it show `The page isn't redirecting properly` but mostly it will load without css and all images will not display while the normal link show the page as it suppose to be with all image and css intact. please i don't know what is the cause or how to fix it, can someone help me out?

See bellow for my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+questions\.php\?postid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ questions/postid/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/postid/([^/]+)/?$ questions.php?postid=$1&$2& [L,QSA]
```

Here is my PHP PDO

```
    <?php 
    session_start(); 
    include('dbconn.php');
    if(isset($_GET['postid'])){

    $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
    $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $FINDID = $_GET['postid'];
    try{
    $find_stmt = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM blogs b 
    INNER JOIN users u
    ON b.UserName = u.username 
    WHERE b.IDS =:postid AND action = 'active'");
    $find_stmt->bindParam(':postid', $FINDID); 
    $find_stmt->execute();
    $FoundResault = $find_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($FoundResault) {
    $IDS  = $FoundResault->IDS;
    $blog_title  = $FoundResault->blog_title;
    $blog_body  = $FoundResault->blog_body;
    $comments  = $FoundResault->comments;
    }
    $checkreply = $replies;

    }catch(PDOException $e){ echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();}

    $db_conn = null;
    }   
    else{
    //echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=".slash."index.php\">";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
  echo $blog_body."<br/>";
    echo $blog_body."<br/>";
    echo $comments."<br/>";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is how the page load

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You problem has nothing to do with PDO or PHP.
Your problem has to do with how relative URLs in HTML documents and for resources like CSS/JavaScript files work.

Lets assume the URL http://example.com/question.php?postid=1234 gives the following output:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style rel="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    Question 1234: Text here
</body>
</html>
```

Your browser now calculates the URL of the style.css to be relative to the directory of the question.php file, which makes it point to http://example.com/style.css.

If you now rewrite the page URL to look like http://example.com/questions/1234, the browser calculates the URL of the css file to be relative to http://example.com/questions, because it thinks that is the directory of the page 1234 and the URL for the css file is now http://example.com/question/style.css.

The easiest solution would be to rewrite in the same directory: rewrite question.php?postid=1234 to question-1234:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^question-([0-9]+)$ /question.php?postid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The second best solution would be to make all paths to CSS and JavaScript files absolute (beginning with a /) so your browser always knows in which directory they are. If you load images from your CSS file, you have to make the paths to the images absolute, too.

Comment: I should replace my old rewrite to this current one you post?@Dennis Birkholz

Comment: I just noticed that is from my rewrite, because i just made and empty text page and the same thing happen in my css was like this `<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>` so i added slash `<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>` and it worked but i do try it im my question page it didn't show

Comment: My rewrite rule does two things:
1. check that the URL does not point to an actual file
2. rewrite to the question.php

Your rewrite rule seems very complicated to me and I do not know what you originally tried to achieve with it. If you only need the two things from above, then use my rule.

Comment: Please i don't know much about the mod rewrite you can give me a simple once to give me clean url instead of `www.site.com/okay.php?id=2&h=hell&q=19`